# How to separate data imported as text in Python into datearray and numeric data

Tags: python, excel, import

I have an excel spreadsheet that has dates in the first column, the rest is the numeric values observed for each attribute. I imported the whole data set using read/readlines function.

**How do I separate the imported data into datearray (first column in the imported dataset) and a separate  matrix of numeric values ( data that I want to work on)?**

For example:

I am importing the following data:

> ObservationDate Attribute1  Attribute2 Attribute3
>
> 01/01/2012          105           101       100
>
> 02/01/2012          101           101       95
>
> 03/01/2012          98            95        97

I would like to create the following from this data:

> DateArrayList = [01/01/2012, 02/01/2012, 03/01/2012]
>
> ```
>              105        101         100
> ```
>
> ValuesMatrix = 
>                    101        101         95
>
> ```
>              98         95          97
> ```

Comment: Wasn't sure how to format the data -- is that what you wanted?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These list comprehensions should do what you're looking for (assume that the data is in testdata.xls, and that it is tab-delimited):

```
with open("testdata.xls") as inf:
    next(inf)
    lines = [l[:-1].split("\t") for l in inf]

date_array_list = [l[0] for l in lines]
values_matrix = [map(int, l[1:]) for l in lines]

print date_array_list
print values_matrix
```

This prints

```
['01/01/2012', '02/01/2012', '03/01/2012']
[[105, 101, 100], [101, 101, 95], [98, 95, 97]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I tried the code that you provided, i don't get an error but both the lists printed are empty - I probably would need to investigate further .Hopefully, it will improve my understanding further.

Comment: This is probably related to your input file. Is your input file a plain text file with tabs delimiting columns? (That is, a traditional .xls file that you created in Excel wouldn't work- try copying its contents into an empty text file)

Comment: Thanks. that worked on importing and separating dates vector, but i get an error on the line:  values_matrix = [map(float,l[1:]) for l in lines] , ValueError : could not convert string to float. Do I have to do any kind of casting ? Thank you.

Comment: That means some value in your input file couldn't be converted into a float. Some reasons this could happen: a) a header row b) numbers having commas (like 1,000,000) c) values like NA or N/A in the table of numbers. If you post a sample of your input file I'm sure it will become clear

Comment: Thanks. I figured this, so I wrote a lamda expression to ignore the NA types. This worked pretty well !

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using numpy, here's the "numpythonic" solution... (Though the other solutions are better if you're not.)

In recent versions of numpy, there's a datetime dtype.  Before that, the most common solution was to use matplotlib's date format (which is a floating point number).

To start with, here's how you'd do it if you wanted to rely on matplolib's date format:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', converters={0:mdates.datestr2num})
dates = data[:,0]
data = data[:,1:]
```

With more recent versions of numpy, you may want to use a `datetime64` dtype for the date array.  In that case (using two passes):

```
import numpy as np
dates = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=np.datetime64, usecols=[0])
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', converters={0:lambda x: -9999.9})
data = data[:,1:]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I tried both but got errors on each. Couldn't find mdates using first method . Invalid literal for float(): 01/01/2012. Any ideas what might be happening here ?

Comment: Well, you need `matplotlib` for the first. The module isn't "mdates", it's `matplotlib.dates`. I'm just using `mdates` as a shorthand. The second version will only work if you're using numpy `1.5` or newer.  Both assume that the dates column is the _first_ column.